# Unable to get environment variable in azure batch VM

Tags: azure, azure-batch

Here is my Azure batch configuration which I am trying to create from microsoft tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-dotnet) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages)

I am trying to get env variables defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-compute-node-environment-variables)

```
                CloudPool pool = batchClient.PoolOperations.CreatePool(
                    poolId: PoolId,
                    targetDedicatedComputeNodes: PoolNodeCount,
                    virtualMachineSize: PoolVMSize,
                    virtualMachineConfiguration: vmConfiguration);

                // Specify the application and version to install on the compute nodes
                pool.ApplicationPackageReferences = new List<ApplicationPackageReference>
                {
                    new ApplicationPackageReference {
                        ApplicationId = "7Zip",
                        Version = "19.00" }
                };

                // Commit the pool so that it's created in the Batch service. As the nodes join
                // the pool, the specified application package is installed on each.
                await pool.CommitAsync();


                    CloudJob job = batchClient.JobOperations.CreateJob();
                    job.Id = JobId;
                    job.PoolInformation = new PoolInformation { PoolId = PoolId };

                    await job.CommitAsync();
                    string taskId = "blendertask01";
                    string commandLine =
                        @"cmd /c echo %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_7Zip%";
                    CloudTask blenderTask = new CloudTask(taskId, commandLine);
                    batchClient.JobOperations.AddTask(JobId, blenderTask);
```

I am expecting the output of `cmd /c echo %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_7Zip%` to give me the path where I can find my application 7zip so that i can install it however I dont get that.
Instead i get `%AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_7Zip%`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_7Zip` we should specify the version also
thus it would become `%AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_7Zip#19.00%\7z1900-x64.exe`

This information is not clearly defined however after few hit and tries I discovered it

[image]

Also that the env variables are not visible when we log on using remote account.